# Recommended DHCP and DNS setup

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, dhcp

I've been tasked with sorting out my office network. Presently there is no internal host name resolution.

Presently the DHCP server is on a Cisco security device and we are using an external (8.8.8.8) DNS server.

I have set up domain server (Windows 2012) and added a DNS server to it. The issue is it only resolves host names of device that are logged into the domain.

We have plenty of devices that do not connect to the domain, so my question is, how do I get them to register their names with the DNS server?

Note some devices use static IP's and some are DHCP.

Comment: Not to downplay Windows, but if all you needed was internal host name resolution the Cisco device could've likely handled that as well.  But jscott is pointing you down the right path now.

Comment: Needed a domain server with Active Directory for testing purposes, otherwise I would have steered clear.

Comment: I perhaps misunderstood the scope of the question. If the AD setup is just for testing, it may be better to get @TheCleaner to post his answer. Mine is based on using AD in production, which may be more overhead than you're looking to maintain.

Comment: @jscott I'm not sure I can set a DNS up on the Cisco ASA 5505, I'm also looking at that route.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest thing [from this AD admin's viewpoint at least] is the following:

1. On your DCs running DNS, [Configure a DNS Server to Use Forwarders](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754941.aspx). Throw Google's DNS addresses in there if you like their service.
2. Get an AD-integrated DHCP server running, see [Integrating DHCP with DNS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771732.aspx). DNS dynamic updates can be configured to allow non-domain devices to register their DNS info via the DHCP server.
3. Add your non-domain-statically-addressed devices to DNS as described in [Adding Resource Records](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772362.aspx).
4. [Set Aging and Scavenging Properties for the DNS Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753217.aspx). Check the TN blog post [Don't be afraid of DNS Scavenging. Just be patient.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2008/03/19/don-t-be-afraid-of-dns-scavenging-just-be-patient.aspx) when you get stuck on this step.

Comment: I was having a look at [TN about DNS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc725703.aspx) and can't find any settings to do with 'Dynamic Updates' on the 2012 Server or the 'Primary/AD Integrated' setting. Do you know if this could be causing the issue?

Comment: Found the properties now!

Comment: In your option 2 - Do you know how to configure the DDNS updates to allow non-domain devices via the DHCP server?

Comment: Enable "Dynamically update DNS A and PTR records for DHCP clients that do not request updates". You may also want to enable "Always dynamically update DNS records" in the same dialog. http://i.imgur.com/E5lTUek.png